# Receiver has no segue with identifier ... programmatically created segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Programmatically created segue crashes the app on performSegueWithIdentifier:, I really don't want to use the storyboard though.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

self.segue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"showInfo" source:self destination:viewController];

//change the background color to white
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//create the table view
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];

//initialize the data source and the delegate to self - as the methods are going to be specified in this script
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;

//register the class for the tableView
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

//now assign the table view to our our viewController's property
self.view = tableView;}
```

Comment: if you don't want to use storyboard then why you are creating class object of storyboard, just simple alloc init and use it no need for create segue object. I suggest use storyboard is one of the power full thing of Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segues can't be created programmatically. Apple's documentation says:

> You do not create segue objects directly. Instead, the storyboard runtime creates them when it must perform a segue between two view controllers.

The initWithIdentifier:source:destination: method is for subclassing purposes.

That said, if you're not using storyboards you don't really need segues anyway. Just instantiate and present the destination view controller when you need to.

Comment: Would you just push onto the navigation stack?

Comment: It depends on the situation... Yes, if you're using a navigation controller you'd probably push onto the stack [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES], but you can also present the destination view controller modally with [self presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES completion:^{}]. You can control the type of modal transition by setting the modalTransitionStyle and modalPresentationStyle properties of the destination view controller before presenting it.